# Python dict with three values in the for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

Using python I have some code that looks like this:

```
for (key, value) in files:
    ...
```

A working list for the above could be:

```
files = [(
   'key1', 'value1'
), ...]
```

I now found this code:

```
for (key, filename, value) in files:
    ...
```

How would the dict look for me to get `key`, `filename` and `value`?

Comment: No, the first loop would **not** unpack your dictionaries. That is not code that would work; `files` is expected to be a list of `(key, value)` *sequences*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, great. Missed that. I've updated the question even though I think you made it clear...

Comment: I think you now know how to answer this yourself, don't you? :-)

Comment: i sure do... not easy being green. thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you want a dict or a list like you have supplied? If you want to keep it as a list you could just extend the tuple to have three items instead of two like so. I assume from your wording you want to know what the files variable would look like in order to fit with that loop. This should suffice:

```
files = [
        ('key1', 'file1', 'value1'),
        ('key2', 'file2', 'value2'),
        ('key3', 'file3', 'value3')
        ]

for (key, file, value) in files:
    print key, file, value

>>key1 file1 value1
>>key2 file2 value2
>>key3 file3 value3
```

If you want it to be a dict you would probably want to format it like this:

```
files = {
        'key1': ('file1', 'value1'),
        'key2': ('file2', 'value2'),
        'key3': ('file3', 'value3')
        }

for key, value in files.iteritems():
    print key, value[0], value[1]

>>key3 file3 value3
>>key2 file2 value2
>>key1 file1 value1
```

However be aware that dict's won't keep the order of the items if that is important to you.